# How to regExp 'zero or one' groups which contain '.*'

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to get `record1`, `record2`, `record3` from text:

```
"Record1 ANY TEXT 123 4 5 Record2 ANOTHER TEXT 90-8098 Record3 MORE TEXT ASD 123"
```

Each record appears ONE or ZERO times.
I use pattern:

```
(Record1.*)?(Record2.*)?(Record3.*)?
```

If each record appears,

```
matcher.group(1) == "Record1 ANY TEXT 123 4 5 Record2 ANOTHER TEXT 90-8098 Record3 MORE TEXT ASD 123"
matcher.group(2) == null
matcher.group(3) == null
```

If I use pattern:

```
(Record1.*)(Record2.*)(Record3.*)

matcher.group(1) == "Record1 ANY TEXT 123 4 5 "
matcher.group(2) == "Record2 ANOTHER TEXT 90-8098 "
matcher.group(3) == "Record3 MORE TEXT ASD 123"
```

It's exatly what I want, but each record can appear zero time and this regexp not suitable

What pattern should I use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to make your quantifiers *non-greedy*, and you want to use *anchors*:

```
^.*?(Record1.*?)?(Record2.*?)?(Record3.*?)?$
```

In your original expression, your `.*` was basically consuming everything to the end of the string, because that's how regular expressions behave, by default (called *greedy matching*). Since the second and third groups were optional, there was no reason for the engine *not* to simply match everything with that first `.*`—it was the most efficient match.

By adding a `?` after any quantifier, *e.g.* `*?` or `+?` or `??` or `{m,n}?`, you instruct the engine to match *as little as possible*, *i.e.* invoke *non-greedy matching*.

So, why the anchors? Well, if you invoke *non-greedy matching*, the engine's going to try to match *as little as possible*. So, it'd match *nothing*, since all your groups are optional! By forcing the whole expression to match the beginning, `^`, as well as the end, `$`, you force to regular expression to find some way to match as few characters as possible via `.*?`, but still match as much as needed to get all the details.

Comment: Are you sure? See [this Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/dtHibuVbON). You may have loaded my answer pre-edit, too—the anchors are absolutely necessary—so try reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

If your text is tightly packed and is composed of just `Record`, why not use split
(if Java calls it split).

split regex:

```
 #  "(?:(?!Record)[\\S\\s])*(Record[\\S\\s]*?)(?=Record|$(?!\\n))"


 (?:
      (?! Record )
      [\S\s] 
 )*
 ( Record [\S\s]*? )
 (?=
      Record
   |  $ (?! \n )
 )
```